# Isomorphism of Elliptic Curves:

Tags: number-theory, elliptic-curves

In Stinson's Cryptography Theory and Practice, a theorem is given without proof:

**Theorem 6.1** Let $E$ be an elliptic curve defined over $Z_p$, where $p$ is prime and $p > 3$. Then there exist positive integers $n_1$ and $n_2$ such that $(E,+)$ is isomorphic to $Z_{n_1} \times  Z_{n_2}$. Further $n_2 | n_2$ and $n_2 | (p - 1)$

While I understand that for some $(e_x,e_y) \in  E, \exists\;(z_x,z_y)\in Z_{n_1} \times  Z_{n_2}:(e_x,e_y) \cong (z_x,z_y)$, I am interested in the mapping $\phi:\phi(E) \mapsto(Z_{n_1} \times  Z_{n_2})$, which is given nowhere in the text and I have had no success finding any such mapping in my searches through other texts or online sources.

Could anyone suggest to me an appropriate source where I might learn about (this mapping)/(constructing this mapping)?

Comment: Wow. Does Stinson really use the notation $Z_p$? This confused me for awhile, but then I realized it must mean $\mathbb{F}_p$ (or at least write it $\mathbb{Z}/p$). In modern mathematics, when talking about elliptic curves or number theoretic things, the notation $\mathbb{Z}_p$ almost always means $p$-adic integers.

Comment: I had a hard time believing that a textbook would just state a result like this without giving a reference to where it is proved.  So I looked it up...and indeed the theorem is baldly asserted, with only list of whole books on elliptic curves given at the end of the chapter.  This kind of absence of scholarship would be bad form in a research paper written for an audience of experts.  I wonder why it is tolerated in books written for students?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$-rational points of $E$ form a finite abelian group $E(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})$, so there exist uniquely defined integers $n_1,n_2,\ldots,n_k$ (the invariant factors) such that $1<n_k$ and $ n_{\ell+1}\mid n_{\ell}$ for all $\ell=1,2,\ldots,k-1$, and
$$
E(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})\cong\mathbb{Z}/n_1\mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z}/n_2\mathbb{Z}\oplus\cdots\oplus\mathbb{Z}/n_k\mathbb{Z}.
$$
This is true for all finite abelian groups.

We need two special properties of elliptic curves to reach the conclusion. For one, the subgroup $E[m]$ of points $P\in E$ with the property $[m]P=0$ (i.e. torsion  of order a factor of $m$) never has more than $m^2$ points. This means that $k\le2$, for if $n_3>1$, then we would have $|E[n_3]|\ge n_3^3$.

So we know that $E(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})\cong\mathbb{Z}/n_1\mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z}/n_2\mathbb{Z}$ for some $n_2\mid n_1$. What this means is that $|E[n_2]\cap E(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})|=n_2^2$. The Weil pairing of  $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$-rational points takes values in the multiplicative group $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}^*$. Furthermore, when restricted to $E[n_2]$ the pairing takes all the roots of unity of order $n_2$ as values. These two items together imply that roots of unity of order $n_2$ must belong to the prime field $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$, and hence $n_2\mid p-1$.

It seems to me that your main question is about constructing an explicit isomorphism $\phi:E(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})\to\mathbb{Z}/n_1\mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z}/n_2\mathbb{Z}$. This is a taller order. Basically you first need to find both $n_2$ and $n_1$. Before that you must find the order of $E(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})$. The Schoof-Elkies-Atkin algorithm is often used there. IIRC in Menezes' book (mentioning it because it is also widely used among crypto people) an algorithm for finding $n_1$ (and thus also $n_2$) is described. Then you "just" need to find a point $P_1$ of order $n_1$, and then a point $P_2$ of order $n_2$ such that the pairing of $([n_1/n_2]P_1,P_2)$ is a primitive root of unity of order $n_2$.
Then an isomorphism is given by
$$
\phi: [x]P_1+[y]P_2\mapsto (x,y).
$$

Because finding $n_1$ and $n_2$ is a complicated process (though the algorithms run in polynomial time) I'm fairly sure that there does not exist a simple way of writing this isomorphism down given, say, the equation of $E$ in Weierstrass form.

Comment: At first I denoted by $E$ both the elliptic curve and the subgroup $E(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})$ of its points with coordinates in the prime field. The context probably made it possible to guess which was intended at each point. But that was bad form anyway. Hopefully my notation is now consistent. Sorry about bumping the answer.

Comment: Hey where can I find a proof for those two specail properties ?

Comment: @Adeek: IIRC Silverman's *The Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves* describes the necessary pieces of theory. For lack of exposure I don't know if other texts would be more accessible to a beginner. When I studied elliptic curves semi-seriously I use Silverman, because I had a suitable background.

Comment: what background is required to study that text ?

Comment: Hey @Jyrki can you explain to me how did you get that $|E[n_3]| \geq n_3^3$?

Comment: Never mind this is from structural theorem for abelian group right ?

Comment: Correct @Adeek. The background requirements for Silverman are quite diverse. Familiarity of basic abstract algebra is needed. He reviews the necessary algebraic geometry (it is a lot simpler, when you concentrate on curves), but the review is quite rapid.

Comment: The notation $E(\mathbb{F}_p)$ is preferable right, because in general we look at $E(k)$ where $k$ is a field (where $2\ne 0,3\ne 0$)

Comment: A fair point @user1952009. I will think about it. Initially I got the vibe that the asker may have a crypto background, and not necessarily be very familiar with field notations other than $\Bbb{Z}/p\Bbb{Z}$, $\Bbb{Q}$, et cetera. So far I have been editing the answer with a view of making clearer how the fact that the full torsion subgroup consists of points rational over the prime field is needed. Admittedly the choice of notation may not be optimal....

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I am familiar with grad level algebra, but not with algebraic geometry yet. Do I need to study it first or can I get away just with abstract algebra ?

Comment: @Adeek: I am not sure. Silverman does review it, and the theory of algebraic curves is less complicated than that of the higher-dimensional objects. This coming from someone who knows a few things about algebraic curves but not much more :-)

Answer (score 0):

Well Matt's comment made me uncertain about notation, bu there's a really good chance you'll find what you're looking for in Silverman's *Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves.* See the chapter on elliptic curves over local fields in particular