# Why is the abelian group of points on an elliptic curve over a finite field isomorphic to the product of at most two cyclic groups?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, abelian-groups, elliptic-curves, cyclic-groups, abelian-varieties

Could anyone explain why the abelian group of points on an elliptic curve over a finite field is isomorphic to at most two cyclic groups? Why is it that it cannot be the product of more than two cyclic groups?

I have tried searching for an answer but the best I could find is that it might be because of Lefschetz principle since an elliptic curve is an abelian variety with dimension 2. But I am not very familiar with algebraic geometry so I don't really understand this answer, let alone know if it is correct.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: What's your background? What book(s) did you read to learn about elliptic curves?

Comment: Maths undergrad, writing a thesis on ECC. I've read some of Hoffstein's An Introduction to Cryptography and some of Koblitz' A Course in Number Theory and Cryptography. I've found a statement of the theorem in Silverman's An Introduction to the
Theory of Elliptic Curves found here https://www.math.brown.edu/~jhs/Presentations/WyomingEllipticCurve.pdf on page 29, but it provides no insight as to why.

Comment: Of course it is not surprising to me that an elliptic curve over a finite field is isomorphic to the product of two cyclic groups, after all an elliptic curve over $\mathbb{C}$ is homeomorphic to a torus, which itself is homeomorphic to the product of two circles. But I would like some more insight as to why this is the case, particularly for finite fields.

Comment: [Related](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/380831/11619).

Answer (score 1):

- For an elliptic curve $\widetilde{E}/\Bbb{F}_q$ - given by a Weierstrass equation - over a finite field you can construct an elliptic curve $E/\Bbb{Q}(\zeta_{q-1})$ whose it is a reduction, then $E[n]\to \widetilde{E}[n]$ **is surjective** under adequate definition of the reduction map (not sure if it is possible to give a two lines proof of this claim).
- $E[n]$ has $n^2$ elements, this follows from the isomorphism from $E/\Bbb{C}$ to a complex torus.

  This implies that *for all $n$*, $\widetilde{E}[n]$ has at most $n^2$ elements, which itself implies that $\widetilde{E}[n]\cong \Bbb{Z}/n_1\Bbb{Z}\times \Bbb{Z}/n_2\Bbb{Z}$ for some $n_1,n_2$ dividing $n$.
- Finally $\widetilde{E}(\Bbb{F}_q)$ is a subgroup of $\widetilde{E}[n]$ with $n=|\widetilde{E}(\Bbb{F}_q)|$, and a subgroup of a product of two cyclic groups is a product of two cyclic groups itself.

Comment: How does the claim in your first point work?

Comment: @HankScorpio You mean the point that doesn't fit in two lines? Somehow the $a$ of the $(a,b)\in E[n]-O$ are roots of a polynomial equation which stays the same in the reduction, but it is a bit technical since there may be some $1/p$ (with $q=p^k$) in the coefficients of the polynomial (this polynomial is the denominator of the rational function $F_n(x)=f_n(x,y)f_n(x,-y)$ such that $[n](x,y)=(f_n(x,y),g_n,(x,y)$)

Answer (score 0):

Let $n=\#E(\mathbb{F}_q)$, which is finite because $\mathbb{F}_q$ is. Then $E(\mathbb{F}_q)\subset E[n]\cong \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Where $E[n]$ is the n-torsion points on $E$? I'm not especially familiar with the notion of n-torsion, would you care to explain why $E[n] \cong \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/n \mathbb{Z}$ please?

Comment: Indeed $E[n]$ is the $n$-torsion subgroup. That material should be available in many places, I don't think I can do better. Perhaps the easiest is to look at *division polynomials*, which are polynomials whose roots correspond exactly to $n$-torsion points. These polynomials have degree $n^2$, which is a big step towards proving the statement. For example, try Silverman's "Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves" exercise III.3.7.

Comment: This is not true unless $n$ is prime to the characteristic.